# Best way to inform user of an SQL Table Update?

Tags: python, mysql, notifications

I have a desktop python application whose data backend is a MySQL database, but whose previous database was a network-accessed xml file(s). When it was xml-powered, I had a thread spawned at the launch of the application that would simply check the xml file for changes and whenever the date modified changed (due to any user updating it), the app would refresh itself so multiple users could use and see the changes of the app as they went about their business.

Now that the program has matured and is venturing toward an online presence so it can be used anywhere. Xml is out the window and I'm using MySQL with SQLAlchemy as the database access method. The plot thickens, however, because the information is no longer stored in one xml file but rather it is split into multiple tables in the SQL database. This complicates the idea of some sort of 'last modified' table value or structure. Thus the question, how do you inform the users that the data has changed and the app needs to refresh? Here are some of my thoughts:

1. Each table needs a last-modified column (this seems like the worst option ever)
2. A separate table that holds some last modified column?
3. Some sort of push notification through a server?
4. It should be mentioned that I have the capability of running perhaps a very small python script on the same server hosting the SQL db that perhaps the app could connect to and (through sockets?) it could pass information to and from all connected clients?

Some extra information:

- The information passed back and forth would be pretty low-bandwidth. Mostly text with the potential of some images (rarely over 50k).
- Number of clients at present is very small, in the tens. But the project could be picked up by some bigger companies with client numbers possibly getting into the hundreds. Even still the bandwidth shouldn't be a problem for the foreseeable future.

Anyway, somewhat new territory for me, so what would *you* do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide some enlightenment as to the number of clients, the amount of data that would have to be pushed to each client, etc? The best solution will depend on the characteristics of your system, with more exotic solutions required for higher-bandwidth applications.

Comment: Updated the OP with some extra info. It's mostly just text data.

Comment: Additionally - does it really matter if the data is very slightly stale? Can you tolerate slightly stale data or is this a user-experience no-no?

Comment: Probably be a user-experience no-no, since there could be several users manipulating the same table (think tasks). I'm also looking for a sort of google-doc situation where you can see where other users are, and even sometimes what they are changing. (Not so much like 'watching them type' or anything though). How stale is "very slightly"?

Comment: One solution might be to decentralise in the same manner as `git` - have a complete local cache of the database, and push updates out as soon as they're made on the central server. Synchronisation might be an issue, but if you do all your application logic on the server side you can prevent any invalid operations being performed.

Comment: The pushes could be triggered by any SELECT, UPDATE or DELETE operation - you would have to find a way to trigger a callback anytime one of these is performed. SQLAlchemy may have a hook for this already - I've not used it, so I can't comment. Alternately you could monkeypatch something into the existing routines, but that's horrible.

Comment: There's enough data in the table (15+mb) that having a local cache is probably a bit overkill. My thought with the small socket server on the host server is that any update made to the SQL server would also just be a small socket communication to the server which would turn around and shoot an "update" signal back to all connected clients. There are hundreds of tables, but the clients will only ever be accessing a few at a time based on the project they're looking at.

Comment: 15MB isn't really too bad (that's what, 60 seconds on a broadband connection?) The changes are probably quite small - I doubt you're changing all 15MB at once - so sending small diffs is probably OK bandwidth wise. The real showstopper here is that every client has a copy of the entire data set, which is good if you want N-backup redundancy but bad if your data is confidential.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9919/discussion-between-cryptite-and-li-aung-yip)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand this is not a client-server application, but rather an application that has a common remote storage.
One idea would be to change to web services (this would solve most of your problems on the long run).
Another idea (if you don't want to switch to web) is to refresh periodically the data in your interface by using a timer.
Another way (and more complicated) would be to have a server that receives all the updates, stores them in the database and then pushes the changes to the other connected clients.
The first 2 ideas you mentioned will have maintenance, scalability and design uglyness issues.
The last 2 are a lot better in my opinion, but I still stick to web services as being the best.

Comment: It has the potential to become a client-server application, as there may be communication between clients, which would need to go through the server. I'm hesitant to just blanket refresh every 5s or so, as that seems like unnecessary data-load. The refresh also doesn't need to include the _changed_ data, as the data to be refreshed is usually small enough that just saying 'refresh' will do the trick. It does seem like at least some kind of web server interaction is going to be the way to go though...

Comment: Web services are scalling better and are easier to maintain in my opinion and if you want an interactive interface with the latest data refreshed you can add some ajax. It all depends on what your application does.

Comment: It may have a web interface at some point, but presently it is intended just to be a desktop application.